# How to commit offset for unique consumers in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

We want all our kafka consumers to receive all the messages from Kafka (from all partitions) so we are generating a unique `group.id` on the fly from each machine. If we have any new machine joining in then that new machine will also have new `group.id` so this logic works and all our kafka consumers (machines) gets all the data from kafka cluster.

Now my confusion is -

- Are there any drawbacks with this approach where we can lose data?
- How should we commit offset if we go with this approach? Should we enable auto commit offset to true or should we manually commit once we have process the data? If we manually commit offset, then is it okay to have all the machines (consumers) to commit offset manually once they have processed the data independently of other machines or only one machine should commit offset after everyone have processed the data?
- Anything else I need to worry about with this approach which I should make sure?

What's the best way with this approach to make sure we are not losing any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q. Are there any drawbacks with this approach where we can lose data?

**Ans** - There is no drawbacks on having multiple kafka consumers. You need to set the settings such that you can don't lose any data.
You can refer to this article which describes on the situations when we can lose data and what settings can help us avoid that: https://blog.softwaremill.com/help-kafka-ate-my-data-ae2e5d3e6576

Q. How should we commit offset if we go with this approach? Should we enable auto commit offset to true or should we manually commit once we have process the data? Also is it okay to have all the machines (consumers) to commit offset manually once they have processed the data independently of other machines or that is gonna cause any problem?

**Ans** - If you don't want to lose data in case of any failures during processing of data and re-reading of data to process again, you should go with manual setting of offsets, as in case of auto commit of offset might lead you to losing some data in case your process died while processing a data partially

Also, please refer to below blogs which elaborates all the situations on how to lose data in kafka:
https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/9/14/how-to-lose-messages-on-a-kafka-cluster-part1
https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/9/18/how-to-lose-messages-on-a-kafka-cluster-part-2

Comment: My situation is specifically talking about all consumers (machines) reading all data from kafka by generating unique group.id on the fly. My main confusion is how should we commit offset if all machines are getting same data? Is it from all the machines or just one machine should commit offset after all consumers have processed them?

Comment: In your case as every machine is a separate consumer with unique group.id so all the consumers will have to manager their offset individually by setting them. If you are going for manual commit of offset, then once the msg is processed, the offset should be committed and then the next poll should be done to read the next message for processing.

Comment: If each machine commit offset manually (after processing the data) independent of other machines in this case then there won't be any problem if any new machines join with new group.id?

Comment: If a new machine joins with new group.id, then it will start reading the messages from the topic based on the initial offset setting of earliest, latest, etc. So if the auto.offset.reset is earliest, then when the fresh consumer comes it will read all the messages in the topic from the beginning.

Comment: yeah we don't want to read from beginning here so if we set it latest then how will it work for that new machine (new consumer) which is joining new? I mean how does `auto.offset.reset latest` works here for the consumers which has unique `group.id` since all machines reads everything from kafka (all data)?

Comment: The ones joining new will read new data only i.e. the data that is written to subscribed topics after the consumer started reading that.

Comment: I see. So is it safe for each machine to commit offset manually once they have processed the data independent of other machines correct?

Comment: Yes it is safe.